# Adding a Custom 'Now' button under 'Published on' header to return current date and time

Tags: metabox, publish

I want to add a new 'Now' button under the 'Published on' header so as to return the current date and time to the post update time. This would help people who want to update their post with a recent time, with ease than publishing with the original publishing time. It would work if, the action of 'Publish' button is given to the 'Now' button as, 'Publish' button returns current date and time to the 'Published On' column. Please help me with the code.
I edited the templates.php and added the following code under the publishing action metabox :

```
    <input name="original_publish" type="hidden" id="original_publish" 
    value="<?php esc__attr_e('Publish') ?>" />
    <?php submit_button( __( 'Now' ), 'primary button-small', 'publish',  
    false, array('accesskey' => 'p' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Please add it to your question.

Comment: I have added the code. The code was copied from meta-boxes.php to templates.php